# Select all fields from custom named aossciation

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a query like so:

```
    $q = $q  
        //->select($this->LessonPupils) // Does not work
        ->select([
            'OutLessonPupils.*', // Does not work
            'Groups.id', 
        ])
        ->where($conditions)
        ->order($order)
        ->contain([
            'Pupils',
            'Pupils.Groups',
            'Pupils.OutLessonPupils'
        ]);
```

I want to select all fields from the `Pupils` association `OutLessonPupils` which uses a table class of `LessonPupils` but I cannot seem to get it to work and I cannot find anything in the documentation about this.

How can I select all fields from `OutLessonPupils`?

Comment: try `->select($this->Pupils->OutLessonPupils)` called by association

Comment: @tarikul05 you, sir, are a life saver

Comment: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-all-fields-from-a-table**

Comment: @ndm I looked at that but you'll notice they say for an instance of the table class which I did. Instead what I needed was an instance of the relation from the table class

Comment: "_what I needed was an instance of the relation from the table class_"... or the target table of the association ;)

Comment: @ndm I used that in the form of `$this->LessonPupils` that was the table class of the association

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work because it's different to `...->OutLessonPupils->target()`, as the alias is different. The latter will use the `OutLessonPupils` alias, the former will use the `LessonPupils ` alias.

Comment: @ndm aha, thanks that clears it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to select by calling associations `->select($this->Pupils->OutLessonPupils)` your code looks like

```
$q = $q->select($this->Pupils->OutLessonPupils)
        ->select([
            'Groups.id', 
        ])
        ->where($conditions)
        ->order($order)
        ->contain([
            'Pupils',
            'Pupils.Groups',
            'Pupils.OutLessonPupils'
        ]);
```